# How can I RecyclerView Different View Selected or UnSelected

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I currently use `RecyclerView` but i can't fix the issue;
If user selected a answer, answer in change `textview` color and background.
If user selected different answer first answer old `textview` color and background.

Codes;

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    _mContext = holder._mAnswersContainer.getContext();
    _mPosition = position;
    holder._mImageAnswer.setImageDrawable(Utils.stringToResource(_mContext,
            _mAnswerList.get(_mPosition).mAnswerImage));
    holder._mImageTextAnswer.setText(_mAnswerList.get(_mPosition).mAnswerText);

    holder._mAnswersContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder._mImageTextAnswer.setTextColor(_mContext.getResources()
                    .getColor(R.color.white));
            holder._mImageTextAnswer.setBackgroundColor(_mContext.getResources()
                    .getColor(R.color.red));

            Log.d(TAG, "Values : " + QuestionsHelper.getInstance(_mContext)
                    .getValues(_mAnswerList.get(_mPosition).mAnswerText));

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your adapter, make a member variable to keep track of which position is selected:

```
private int mSelected = -1;
```

Inside your `onBindViewHolder` (although it might work inside `onCreateViewHolder` as well):

```
int color;
if(position == mSelected){
    color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.selectedColor);
}else{
    color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.regularColor);
}

// Set the color
viewHolder.yourView.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

Create some helper functions for your RecyclerView adapter to handle the selection:

```
public void selectPosition(int selected){
    mSelected = selected;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void resetSelected(){
    mSelected = -1;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Wherever you want to set the selected item just call `adapter.selectPosition()`. And clear the selection with `adapter.resetSelected()`